# doc-view rendering of pdf files

Tags: pdf, docview

I have emacs 27.2 installed on my M1 Macbook pro.  With a lot of pdfs when I first visit the file from dired, the font rendering is badly messed up -- a lot of the characters are replaced either by white space and/or boxes.  However, if I type C-c C-c, after a bit of a pause, the rendering gets cleaned up.  I'm also using gs version 9.56.1 which is installed via homebrew.  I don't have this problem on another mac which is an intel mac.  Clearly the fonts are present, since typing C-C C-C fixes it.  Are there any suggestions as to how I can fix this behavior?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I recommend looking into `pdf-tools` which IMO is *so* much nicer than doc-view for viewing PDFs inside Emacs.

Comment: I'm actually already using pdf-tools.

Comment: Oh, so why are you interested in doc-view then?

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused.  If I installed pdf-tools, does that take over from doc-view when I visit a file in a dired list?

Comment: It should take over any time you visit a PDF file in Emacs, however you did it.  If you're not seeing `PDFView` in the mode line as the major mode (`pdf-view-mode`) then I don't think you have `pdf-tools` set up properly?